# Which database can be used to store the hash prefixes obtained from google safebrowsing api?

Tags: safe-browsing

For storing data (prefixes of hashes of urls) obtained from google safebrowsing api https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/ , which is the database recommended ?

I want to create a local databases for storing the hash prefixes and full hashes obtained from the google safebrowsing api. In order to check the integrity of database, we need to calculate the sha-256 (checksum) of the prefixes in local databases in lexicographic order after each update call.

Has anyone tried to do anything similar to my requirement ?

Comment: Did you implement this ? If yes, what did you use and which database setup will you prefer.  I am actually implementing the google safe browsing API v4 setup. So, had the same question